# Как преобразовать UTF строку, содержащую коды символов и символы в строку только с символами?

Tags: android-ndk, android, java

Есть у меня приложение под Андройд, которое должно запускаться когда пользователь открывает определенный файл.

Когда моё приложение запускается я вытаскиваю из **Intent** имя выбранного файла следующим образом: 
    **String fileName = intent.getDataString();**

Проблема заключается в том, что если имя файла содержит символы **[** и **]**, то они заменяются в результирующей строке на **%5B** и **%5D**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно преобразовать коды обратно в символы или избежать данного поведения вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему используя [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)